# INFO:tensorflow:Summary name dnn/hiddenlayer_0:fraction_of_zero_values is illegal

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to train DNNRegressor in tensorflow on a toy example, and while the code works fine, the following lines are printed as part of the output:

> INFO:tensorflow:Summary name dnn/hiddenlayer_0:fraction_of_zero_values
>   is illegal; using dnn/hiddenlayer_0_fraction_of_zero_values instead.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Summary name dnn/hiddenlayer_0:activation is illegal;
>   using dnn/hiddenlayer_0_activation instead. INFO:tensorflow:Summary
>   name dnn/hiddenlayer_1:fraction_of_zero_values is illegal; using
>   dnn/hiddenlayer_1_fraction_of_zero_values instead.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Summary name dnn/hiddenlayer_1:activation is illegal;
>   using dnn/hiddenlayer_1_activation instead. INFO:tensorflow:Summary
>   name logits:fraction_of_zero_values is illegal; using
>   logits_fraction_of_zero_values instead. INFO:tensorflow:Summary name
>   logits:activation is illegal; using logits_activation instead.

Here is my code (the above text is printed when the last line in the code below is executed):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNRegressor, SKCompat, infer_real_valued_columns_from_input

x_train=np.random.normal(size=(100, 1))
x_train=x_train.astype(dtype=np.float32,copy=False)
y_train=np.sin(x_train)

feature_columns=infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(x_train)

classifier = DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[100,50],optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01),activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)

est=SKCompat(classifier)
est.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,batch_size=5,max_steps=100)
```

I tried to search for this in google but none of the [results](https://www.google.es/search?q=INFO%3Atensorflow%3ASummary%20name%20dnn%2Fhiddenlayer_0%3Afraction_of_zero_values%20is%20illegal&oq=INFO%3Atensorflow%3ASummary%20name%20dnn%2Fhiddenlayer_0%3Afraction_of_zero_values%20is%20illegal&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.549j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=INFO:tensorflow:Summary%20name%20dnn/hiddenlayer_0:fraction_of_zero_values%20is%20illegal&filter=0&*) seems to be relevant to this particular case. Is there some way to modify the code to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these messages are just a warning; and your code should be working fine.

Looks like the estimator code needs update. Might be worth file a TensorFlow github issue on this. More context here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py#L89